# Android Out of Memory Error using DrawableAnimation

Tags: android, animation, memory

I´m trying to run an app with several DrawableAnimation.

- Structure

  - MainActivity - ButtonA - ButtonB - ButtonC - ButtonD - ButtonE - Button F

    - ActivityA - ButtonA1 - ButtonA2 - ButtonA3 - ButtonA4
    - ActivityB - ButtonB1 - ButtonB2 - ButtonB3 - ButtonB4
    - ActivityC - ButtonC1 - ButtonC2 - ButtonC3
    - Settings - Name - Date - Numbers -

So, each button Start a Short DrawableAnimation, each animation has 30 to 50 images. I know it´s a little ambitious, but I´m sure there´s a way to do it.

Each Animation start with this code:

```
private void addListenerOnButton() {
view = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.startanimation);
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        frameAnimation.stop(); frameAnimation = null;
        view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.animation01);
        frameAnimation = (AnimationDrawable) view.getBackground();
        frameAnimation.start();
```

I tried to clean memory with animation stop or animation null, but it doesn't work.
I tried with bitmap recycle but, If the user wants to run an Animation more than one time it doesn't work cause recycle don't use it anymore.
I know that garbage collector is not the way.

So, how can I run DrawableAnimation and Clean Memory after finish it, to avoid the Out of Memory error?

Comment: are you getting OutOfMemory after a few animations or does it occur during your first animation?

Comment: It occur after the second or sometimes the third animation. Obviously the memory work too hard and then colapse. Someone told me, I should use AsyncTask  or Threaf or Runnable... But I don´t know how to use it. Still learning...

Comment: I think you've got a memory leak somewhere but i wouldn't be so sure that it is in the animation. I suggest to google "memory leak android". Or maybe the images in your animation are just too big

Comment: It probably be the size of the images, each images has 15kb, each animation has 30 to 50 images, so, memory will be increasing. I just want to memory clean itself after each animation, so the next animation work properly.

Comment: yes, memory should clean itself, but when it doesn't you should suspect there might be a memory leak. I again suggest you to google a little bit, look for memory leak, garbage collector and also memory leaks in android. btw, when you say each image is 15kb, keep in mind that there's a difference between a compressed image and a bitmap, you can store compressed image but when it comes to rendering you need the bitmap, this meaning that 15kb of compressed image could use much more memory as bitmap...!

Comment: I´m still stuck with this problem, anyone can help me?

Answer (score 1):

for me this code works fine

```
largeHeap=true
```

you have to put in application tag of manifest

Comment: [Please format your code properly](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)